# how to check and select rows where the postgresql jsonb column overlap with certain array

Tags: postgresql

For example I have a table with a jsonb column, not nested, just like `[1,2,3]`, How can I select rows that overlaps (has same element) with one certain array, say like `[1,2,6,8,3]`?

I tried with

```
select * from mytable
where TRANSLATE(myjsonb::jsonb::text, '[]','{}')::INT[]  && ARRAY[1,2,6,8,3]
limit 100
```

But it's not working. I'm fairly new for postgresql. Thank you

Comment: id--myjsonb\n 1--[1,2]\n 2--[4,5]\n 3--[2,6]\n it should return row 1 and row3

Answer (score 1):

You can do this judge as below:

```
postgres=# select array(select jsonb_array_elements_text('[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb)) as arr;
   arr   
---------
 {1,2,3}
(1 row)

postgres=# select array(select jsonb_array_elements_text('[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb))::int[] && '{1,2,4}'::int[] as bool;
 bool 
------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select array(select jsonb_array_elements_text('[1, 2, 3]'::jsonb))::int[] && '{5,6,7}'::int[] as bool;
 bool 
------
 f
(1 row)
```

The clearer examples:

```
postgres=# \d my_jsonb
  Table "public.my_jsonb"
 Column | Type  | Modifiers 
--------+-------+-----------
 data   | jsonb | 

postgres=# select * from my_jsonb ;
      data       
-----------------
 [1, 2, 3]
 [2, 1, 6, 7, 8]
 [2, 1, 2]
 [3, 4, 5]
 [3, 8, 5, 9]
(5 rows)

postgres=# select
    array(select jsonb_array_elements_text(data))::int[] as arr,
    array(select jsonb_array_elements_text(data))::int[] && '{1,2,4}'::int[] as bool 
from 
    my_jsonb;
     arr     | bool 
-------------+------
 {1,2,3}     | t
 {2,1,6,7,8} | t
 {2,1,2}     | t
 {3,4,5}     | t
 {3,8,5,9}   | f
(5 rows)
```

Comment: but it will concatenate jsonb from each row all together into one array and overlap with the target array... How could I overlap jsonb from each row with the target one?

Comment: No, it wouldn't concat them all together, it just get the overlap for each row. Just see my new examples above. @qqxlafk